# How do make Windows key (Super_L) to NOT bring up Search menu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xmodmap

I would prefer to use Windows key as Super_L in emacs and possibly other apps. However, the key is programmed to bring up Ubuntu Search Apps menu. Is there any way to disable this shortcut, in other words un-map the Windows key from Search Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to un-map the key using CompizConfig Settings Manager, via Ubuntu Unity Plugin sub-menu. I had to disable "Key to show the Dash, Launcher and Help Overlay" (see picture)[image]

Answer (score 2):

To disable the binding of <kbd>Super</kbd> for bringing up the activities overview, issue following command in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

You can undo this with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter overlay-key
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, this did not work for me, the win key still brings up search/apps menu. I also tried restarting after the command and also confirmed the setting via dconf-editor.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity. `unity-tweak-tool` shows in unity->launcher->additional 'Show the launcher':<Super> shortcut but there is no way to delete or modify it

Comment: How can I know from your question that use the Unity desktop?